# JOIN with SQL across multiple tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with multiple tables, which I need to join and then query
This database has the following tables:

```
**Address** with unique reference column AddressNo
**Employee** with unique reference columns AddressNo & PersonNo
**EmploymentLink** with unique reference columns PersonNo & BusinessNo
**Business** with unique reference column  BusinessNo
**BusinessSICCode** with unique reference column BusinessNo
```

I would like to link all these tables so I can run a query to pull back data across all tables, because there are multiple tables, I'm not sure how to do it and would appreciate any help guidance

Below is the query I have come up with so far

```
SELECT Employee.*, Address.*,Business.*,BusinessSICCode.*
FROM Employee,Address,Business,BusinessSICCode 
JOIN Employee ON Employee.AddressNo = Address.AddressNo
JOIN Employee ON Employee.PersonNo = EmploymentLink.PersonNo 
JOIN Business ON Business.BusinessNo = EmploymentLink.BusinessNo 
JOIN BusinessSICCode ON BusinessSICCode.BusinessNo = Business.BusinessNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going

```
SELECT * FROM
Address a INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.AdressNo = a.AddressNo
INNER JOIN EmploymentLine l on l.PersonNo = e.PersonNo
INNER JOIN Business b ON b.BusinessNo = l.BusinessNo
INNER JOIN BusinessSICCode c ON c.BusinessNo = b.BusinessNo
```

You can change the INNER JOINS to LEFT JOINS if you have some tables that may not have records in them but still want the values from the parent tables.

Comment: Thank you Palehorse, you made it look so simple and me such a fool - this is just what I wanted - thank you

Comment: My pleasure, not foolish at all, just been doing this for years. If this resolved you issue please mark it as the correct answer, it would be most appreciated.